# Rails 3: What is the correct Rails way of doing custom types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, types, ruby-on-rails-3.1, custom-type

I'm doing a fairly complicated model on Ruby on Rails right now, and I was wondering what the correct "Rails" way of doing "custom types" for attributes was. For example, I have a table `businesses` which has a string attribute `region`. But region can only be one of a predefined list of possibilities (that could later be expanded). My question is: where do I define this Region type?

I know I could make a specific `regions` table (i.e. a Region model) which could house all the options, and then I could make an association between the models that have regions to that table. The problem is that I have many of these types on my model, so I would end up with more than half the tables in my database being "custom type tables" that only store the possible values for these types. Is that practical?

I also read that you could do this through validations (i.e. validate when saving a record, that the variables were within the possible values). This seems very impractical, since I want to make this model expandable, and form views would need to load the possible values of types into select boxes, etc. If I used this method, every time I needed to add a new possible value for a type, I'd have to change the validation and the views.

Is there a standard way of doing something like this? Something like defining types (maybe models without DB backing?) where I could list all the possible values easily?

Thank you for any help or suggestions on this. It's been bothering me for a long time while doing RoR apps, and I'm tired of hacking around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are many different ways to do it. Personally I would keep things very simple and DRY.

In an initializer, set arrays in the global scope:

```
REGIONS = ["region A", "region B", "region C"]
```

In the models, use validations as you wrote. Check that the value is in the `REGIONS` array.

In the views, use Rails helpers to populate selects, radios etc. from the `REGIONS` array. If you always have the same select, write your own helper region_select for instance.

Comment: This seems like a great solution for what I'm trying to do. Thank you very much! I will still make some custom type tables/models for the custom types that are expanded by the app at runtime, but the rest of the custom types can be perfectly defined with this method.